# AJAX call each() and find() application

Tags: ajax, post, find, each

The message alert does not appear after the post call under ajax.

Given the following ajax call:

```
var val= 1;
$.post("ajax.php", { information: val }, function(result)
{
  $(result).find("div").each(function()
  {
     if($(this).text()=="OK")
      {
        alert("OK");
      }
   });
});
```

and the ajax.php file:

```
<?php
 if($_POST['information']==1)
 {
  ?><div>You must fill all the fields</div><?php
  ?><div>The title must be between 10 and 30 characters</div><?php
  ?><div>Please insert your email in the field</div><?php
  ?><div id="answer">OK</div><?php
 }
 ?>
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: corrected errors found by Benny. corrected post syntax and $(result) syntax

Answer (score 1):

In your example you have faulty $.post syntax.

```
$.post("ajax.php"), { information: $val }, function(result){
  // Callback code
});
```

The correct syntax would be.

```
$.post("ajax.php", { information: $val }, function(result){
   // Callback code
});
```

Also using $ as part of the $val variable name is confusing. It can trick developers into thinking that it has something to do with the jQuery variable, even though it's just part a local variable name.  I would recommend doing just...

```
var val = 1;
```

Comment: I corrected the errors but it does not work either. I've already use post methods before.. so it is ok with that. My question would be: Are the syntaxes of each and find functions correctly written?

Comment: I guess you have to do $(result).find() instead of just result.find().

Comment: Thanks buddy, now the code is running (before the code was broken) but it looks like the function does not find the "OK".

Comment: No problem. That's strange, I guess next step is to verify that the expected html actually gets returned from ajax.php. You can inspect ajax request responses using Firebug (for Firefox) or Chrome developer tools (for Chrome obviously).

Comment: The each() should be fine if you just get the proper response. http://jsfiddle.net/8u55S/

Comment: Well in the example you see should be fine but it is not, so something is wrong with the $(result) since the function does not recognize the html structure.